# How to delete directly from Listbox (MVVM)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am trying to learn MVVM c# and tried to create a simple program where you add name to the listbox. Now I would like to delete some items from the listbox when pressed on them and then press "delete me" button by using another command but couldnt find a way to do it.

Viewmodel is:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private Model _model;

        public ViewModel(Model model)
        {
            AddCommand = new AddNameCommand(this);
         //   DeleteCommand = new DeleteNameCommand(this);
            _model = model;
        }

        public string CurrentName
        {
            get { return _model.CurrentName; }
            set
            {
                if (value == _model.CurrentName)
                    return;
                _model.CurrentName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

       public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
        
      
      
        public ObservableCollection<string> AddedNames
        {
            get { return _model.AddedNames; }
        }
        class AddNameCommand : ICommand
        {
            ViewModel parent;

            public AddNameCommand(ViewModel parent)
            {
                this.parent = parent;
                parent.PropertyChanged += delegate { CanExecuteChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty); };
            }

            public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

            public bool CanExecute(object parameter) { return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(parent.CurrentName); }

            public void Execute(object parameter)
            {
                parent.AddedNames.Add(parent.CurrentName);
                parent.CurrentName = null;
            }
        }

        class DeleteNameCommand : ICommand
        {
            
            public void Execute(object parameter)
            {
                parent.AddedNames.Remove(...?);

            }
        }


        public ICommand AddCommand { get; private set; }
    }
}
```

View is

```html
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="150"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="5"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <DockPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="Added Names"  
        DockPanel.Dock="Top" Margin="5,3"/>
            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding AddedNames}"></ListBox>
        </DockPanel>

        <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1"  
    VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="5"  
     Background="Gray" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />

        <Grid Grid.Column="2">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="Name" Margin="5,3"/>
            <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"   Text="{Binding CurrentName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="5,3"/>

            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="Your name is:" Margin="5,3"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"  Text="{Binding CurrentName}"  Margin="5,3"/>


            <Button Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  
         Content="Add Me" Command="{Binding AddCommand}" Margin="5,3" MinWidth="75" />
            <Button Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  
         Content="Delete Me" Command="{Binding DeleteCommand}" Margin="5,29,0,-23" MinWidth="75" />

        </Grid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

and model is

```
public class Model
    {
        public string CurrentName { get; set; }
       

        public ObservableCollection<string> AddedNames { get; } = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    }
```

Comment: The way you set your datakontext is odd. Why are you creating a new viewmodel object in your viewmodel class?

Comment: @DenisSchaf I have added that object to my mainwindow class. which would be best?

Comment: You may pass the SelectedItem of the ListBox to the CommandParameter of the Delete Button. The item will then be available to the Command via the Execute parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `SelectedName` property to the view model:

```
public string SelectedName { get; set; }
```

Bind the `ListBox` in the view to it:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding AddedNames}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedName}" />
```

And then simply use the value of the property in your command:

```
public void Execute(object parameter)
{
   parent.AddedNames.Remove(parent.SelectedName);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

either have a SelectedName property

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding AddedNames}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedName}"/>
```

or what i like to use is a delete in the line

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding AddedNames}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <DockPanel>
                <Button DockPanel.Dock="Right" Content="X" Command="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl}}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
            </DockPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

and

```
public void Execute(object parameter)
{
    parent.AddedNames.Remove((string)parameter);
}
```